# Nginx rewrite URL to not show file path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Apologies in advance. I'm a beginner with Nginx and have a lot to learn with server administration. After doing a bunch of searching and reading, I'm really not understanding a direct solution to my problem.

With Nginx I have the following URL that awkwardly shows the filepath on my server and the .html extension:

bwillis.info/artifact/faeriefm/faerieFM.html

I'd simply like to be able to access that page with:

bwillis.info/faeriefm

How can I accomplish this? It's my understanding that I'd use the "rewrite" function. But I'm having trouble breaking down and making sense of the syntax on the examples here:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Folder Structure:

index.html sits at the root

Four pages sit one folder deep in folder called "artifact" so: bwillis.info/artifact/samplepage.html

One additional page, the one I used in the example, sits one more folder deep inside the "faeriefm" folder. so: bwillis.info/artifact/faeriefm/faerieFM.html

Server Configuration File:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/bwillis.info/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name bwillis.info www.bwillis.info;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: the index.html is at the root. From there are 5 branching pages located inside the "artifact" folder. One of those pages, faerieFM.html, is one extra folder deep, inside the faeriefm folder.

So four of the pages are bwillis.info/artifact/samplepage.html  and the one I just mentioned is bwillis.info/artifact/faeriefm/faerieFM.html

I can rename it, sure. But what's the inconsistency exactly?

Comment: @RichardSmith okay, edited. But do you have a solution? It seems like you had some idea of what I should do at least.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm a beginner here. What do you mean by "server configuration", how do I add /artifact to the end of my existing root directive? Will that interfere with my main landing page, index.html which is currently at the root directory? I can post any information needed, but I just need to know exactly what to post.

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer as it stands at the moment. Do you have a working Nginx server? If so you need to show its configuration files in your question so that we point to which parts need to be changed. If not, then your question is probably off-topic for this site and you may have more success over on superuser.com

Comment: @RichardSmith Okay there it is. Updated the question. Does that help you at all? I'll be honest here. My setup is an extremely cookie cutter nginx server block setup. I don't think any further detail on my end is going to help bring anyone closer to a solution. This seems like a very standard problem. I don't often see big ugly filepaths and .html extensions when I go browsing the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of files located in the folder `/var/www/bwillis.info/html/artifact/faeriefm/`. An HTML file called `faerieFM.html` and some resource files which appear to be loaded using a path-relative URL.

In order for your path-relative URLs to work correctly, you will need to use a trailing `/` in the URI of the original HTML file.

For example:

```
location /faeriefm {
    root /var/www/bwillis.info/html/artifact;
    index faerieFM.html;
}
```

The above example uses a prefix location, as there are a number of URIs beginning with `/faeriefm`, including: `/faeriefm/` and `/faeriefm/javascript.js`. The `root` directive ensures that they find the correct folder for the files.

Comment: This kind of worked. The page successfully loads. But none of the javascript files located in that folder, embedded on that page load. The console says they all try loading at bwillis.info/javascript.js  instead of bwillis.info/artifact/faeriefm/javascript.js. Is there a way to get these files to load?

Comment: So this worked. But I still have some lingering questions. one of my scripts that was one directory up called artifactscripts.js failed to load in the HTML file with src="../artifactscripts.js" but successfully loaded when I copied the file to the faeriefm folder & changed it to just src="artifactscripts.js"

This doesn't make sense to me because all of my images load just fine, and they're accessed with src="../../assets/portfolio/image.png" 

It just feels so inconsistent. For my script going one directory up was an issue, but for my images it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Your confusing the URI for the file with its physical location in the files system. The URI `../artifactscripts.js` relative to `/faeriefm/` becomes `/artifactscripts.js`, which resolves to a pathname of `/var/www/bwillis.info/html/artifactscripts.js`. You probably don't want to use path-relative URIs with `../` in them, if you are then going to set up special top level locations such as `location /faeriefm`. The two schemes are not compatible with each other.

Comment: how should write it in the HTML file then so it is more compatible? I guess what's the best practice here?

Comment: I can't comment on best practice - I think this is a matter of how you want to design it. In my opinion, you have a choice: (1) The URI for `artifactscripts.js` in the `artifact` folder is `/artifact/artifactscripts.js` - use that. (2) Scrap the current URI for `faerieFM.html` and use `/artifact/faeriefm/` instead, in which case the `../` style URI will magically start working again.

Comment: Ah, so the first option breaks testing on my local computer when I edit the HTML with "/artifact/artifactscripts.js" is there a way to fix it on the local end by possibly using the <base> tag?

Comment: I cannot comment on the test environment of your local computer.